# Express res.locals.someVariable use in hbs (handlebars template)

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to pass my session variables to my handlebars templates but am getting stuck. Right now I am using this in my app.configure function:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        console.log(res.locals.session);
        next();
});
```

It logs correctly to the console, but when I try to use the "session" variable in my handlebars template, nothing shows up. Here is part of my template:

```
<body>
        <nav>
            {{> topBarPartial}}

            {{> secondaryBarPartial}}
        </nav>
        <div>
            <p>before</p>
            {{session}}
            <p>after</p>
            {{> mainPartial}}
        </div>

        {{> footerPartial}}
</body>
```

Here is what is being logged by the console:

```
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  userId: 45253262,
  name: 'Austin' }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I finally found my solution. It turns out that I was calling this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        console.log(res.locals.session);
        next();
});
```

after

```
app.use(app.router);
```

It actually needs to be before the app.router, but after

```
app.use(express.session({
        secret: '***********'
    }));
```

Comment: Yes. In express, your route functions are executed *inside* the app.router middleware.